# How can I get Google Calendar API status_code in Python when get list events?

Tags: python, google-api, http-status-code-404, google-calendar-api, google-api-python-client

I try to use Google Calendar API

```
events_result = service.events().list(calendarId=calendarId,
                                          timeMax=now,
                                          alwaysIncludeEmail=True,
                                          maxResults=100, singleEvents=True,
                                          orderBy='startTime').execute()
```

Everything is ok, when I have permission to access the calendarId, but it will be errors if wrong when I don't have calendarId permission.

I build an autoload.py function with schedule python to load events every 10 mins, this function will be stopped if error come, and I have to use SSH terminal to restart autoload.py manually
So i want to know:

How can I get status_code, example, if it is 404, python will PASS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer:

*You can use a try/except block within a loop to go through all your calendars, and skip over accesses which throw an error.*

#### Code Example:

To get the error code, make sure to import `json`:

```py
import json
```

and then you can get the error code out of the Exception:

```py
calendarIds = ["calendar ID 1", "calendar ID 2", "calendar Id 3", "etc"]

for i in calendarIds:
    try:
        events_result = service.events().list(calendarId=i,
                                          timeMax=now,
                                          alwaysIncludeEmail=True,
                                          maxResults=100, singleEvents=True,
                                          orderBy='startTime').execute()
    except Exception as e:
        print(json.loads(e.content)['error']['code'])
        continue
```

#### Further Reading:

- [Python Try Except - w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp)
- [Python For Loops - w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [@Rafa Guillermo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63479103/how-can-i-get-google-calendar-api-status-code-in-python-when-get-list-events/63487429#63487429), I uploaded the full code to the autoload.py program, but I also wanted to know, how to get response json or status_code for request Google API.

The solution:

```
try:
 code here
except Exception as e:
            continue
```

```
import schedule
import time
from datetime import datetime
import dir
import sqlite3
from project.function import cmsCalendar as cal
db_file = str(dir.dir) + '/admin.sqlite'

def get_list_shop_from_db(db_file):
    cur = sqlite3.connect(db_file).cursor()
    query = cur.execute('SELECT * FROM Shop')
    colname = [ d[0] for d in query.description ]
    result_list = [ dict(zip(colname, r)) for r in query.fetchall() ]
    cur.close()
    cur.connection.close()
    return result_list

def auto_load_google_database(list_shop, calendarError=False):
    shopId = 0
    for shop in list_shop:
        try:
            shopId = shopId+1
            print("dang ghi vao shop", shopId)
            service = cal.service_build()
            shop_step_time_db = list_shop[shopId]['shop_step_time']
            shop_duration_db = list_shop[shopId]['shop_duration']
            slot_available = list_shop[shopId]['shop_slots']
            slot_available = int(slot_available)
            workers = list_shop[shopId]['shop_workers']
            workers = int(workers)
            calendarId = list_shop[shopId]['shop_calendarId']
            if slot_available > workers:
                a = workers
            else:
                a = slot_available
            if shop_duration_db == None:
                shop_duration_db = '30'
            if shop_step_time_db == None:
                shop_step_time_db = '15'

            shop_duration = int(shop_duration_db)
            shop_step_time = int(shop_step_time_db)

            shop_start_time = list_shop[shopId]['shop_start_time']
            shop_start_time = datetime.strptime(shop_start_time, "%H:%M:%S.%f").time()
            shop_end_time = list_shop[shopId]['shop_end_time']
            shop_end_time = datetime.strptime(shop_end_time, "%H:%M:%S.%f").time()

            # nang luc moi khung gio lay ra tu file Json WorkShop.js
            booking_status = cal.auto_load_listtimes(service, shopId, calendarId, shop_step_time, shop_duration, a,
                                                     shop_start_time,
                                                     shop_end_time)


        except Exception as e:
            continue

def main():

    list_shop = get_list_shop_from_db(db_file)
    auto_load_google_database(list_shop)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    schedule.every(5).minutes.do(main)
    while True:
        # Checks whether a scheduled task
        # is pending to run or not
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)
```